# Changing Notification title with JSON pushes

Tags: parse-platform

Normally when you push a notification in " Plain text " option , the user can read the beginning of your notification and click on it to reveal it all .

However when I choose "JSON" option , and send my notification with JSON way , it shows up like this (red line just to hide the name of the app) [image: notice the string that I can't change]

So Can I modify the notification content here ? rather than having "Notification received"